# Isolating multiple mounted user-space file systems on the running microservice

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My situation: I have a microservice running Ubuntu 18.04 on GKE for evaluating the user's code. Every time, a user logs into her project, the service receives the user ID and project ID and it mounts a correct GCS bucket through a [user-space file system](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) based on these IDs. This service can be accessed by multiple users at the same time.

My goal: How can I achieve user isolation in a way that each user "lives" in their own filesystem and can't "see" other mounted file systems?

Ideas:

- Run a docker container inside a docker container
- Start pods on demand every time a new user logs in
- Isolate users on the OS level

Answer (score 1):

What about to let your application to spawn a Pod for each user using [SecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)?

You could specify `fsGroup` (from the doc: *volumes that support ownership management are modified to be owned and writable by the GID specified in fsGroup*) in order to enhance the segregation you want.

The challenging part is the clean-up of old Pods no more used, so it must be supervised by your application or, in case of *logout* (I guess since I don't have so many details about your architecture) performs a clean-up taking advantages of the label system provided by Kubernetes.

Comment: This sounds intriguing. Could you please nudge me in the correct direction of spawning pod using SecurityContext?
Would the spawning process be on-demand (somehow from the code?) or would Kubernetes handle that?


I was also thinking that I could define a [work queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/) where each job would be user's session.

Comment: I think you should use the Kubernetes SDK according to your preferred language: you can find many examples and just need to interact with the API Server creating or deleting the Pod resources using the provided schemas